# Session is not working and showng keyError at task

Tags: html, django, session

Hello i was trying to fix my session but it did not work. it shows KeyError at /task/
'tasK'. I tried many things . I changed the setting but it didnt work too:

```
SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = True
SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE != DEBUG
```

my code is:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django import forms

class TaskForm(forms.Form):
    input = forms.CharField(label="New Task", max_length=255)  
    



def show_task(request):
    if "tasK" != request.session:
        request.session["tasK"] = []

    return render(request, "hi/j.html", {"tasK": request.session["tasK"]})

def show(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = TaskForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            task = form.cleaned_data["input"]
            request.session["tasK"].append(task)  
            request.session.modified = True  
            request.session.save()
        else:
            return render(request, "hi/j.html", {"form": form})

    return render(request, "hi/k.html", {"forms": TaskForm()})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is with this block

```
if "tasK" != request.session:
    request.session["tasK"] = []
```

Change that to:

```
tasK = request.session.get("tasK")
if not tasK:
   request.session["tasK"] = []
```